# KFIFO APIs: Difference kfifo_put and kfifo_in (or kfifo_get and kfifo_out)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

It is not obvious from the implementation in `include/linux/kfifo.h` and `lib/kfifo.c` whether or not there is any difference between the `kfifo_in` and `kfifo_put` ( OR `kfifo_out` and `kfifo_get`) APIs. They essentially do the similar functionality, but because they distinctly exist there must be difference in the two.

Also, is it that `kfifo_put` provides a circular queue like functionality (i.e. waits if queue is full), whereas `kfifo_in` provides a ring buffer like functionality (i.e. if the ring is full overwrite the oldest entry and push the read pointer to next position) ?

Answer (score 2):

`kfifo_put`/`get` handle a single element; `kfifo_in`/`out` handle multiple elements.

Comment: Is there no other difference?